# Rails 4 - .js files not running in production environment - Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku

I'm having trouble loading my .js files in production on Heroku.

I know the files are being picked up from the asset pipeline as they are working in development just fine but I am unable to get the .js working in production.

I have created `/assets/javascripts/notification.js` containing:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("span").click(function() {
    $(".notice").delay(200).fadeOut(2000, function() {
    });
  });
});
```

My `/assets/javascripts/application.js` file contains:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

in development, this works great.

When I deploy to Heroku, I can see that the code is displayed within a single `application.js` file, except the document ready function is stripped out, see below production .js file:

```
<script src="/assets/application-b9a733c3cc0929ae852e45a6c3a2a5f6.js" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
```

My `config/production.rb` contains:

```
config.serve_static_files = ENV['RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES'].present?
config.assets.compile = true
```

Comment: I have literally just solved this issue: I needed to run a rake assets:precompile - Why does this have to be run? Why doesn't Rails do this automatically? Could I invoke this?

Comment: Lots more info about this here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-4-asset-pipeline.  Did you add the rails_12factor gem?

Comment: rails_12factor was already installed - as Unixmonkey stated, this has likely been missed due to an earlier precompile.

Answer (score 1):

If you install the [rails_12factor](https://github.com/heroku/rails_12factor) gem [as Heroku Recommends](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-rails4#heroku-gems) it will automatically run `rake assets:precompile` on deploy (through a gem dependency named [rails_serve_static_assets](https://github.com/heroku/rails_serve_static_assets)).

It may skip this step if it sees a public/assets/manifest.* file or a /public/assets directory, which tells it you've already compiled the assets, and it doesn't need to be done again.

Comment: I already have rails_12factor installed, I think this has been skipped, what's the best way to avoid this being skipped in future?

Comment: @JustDanLee Check the output when you deploy for a firmer answer, but I'm thinking you should change `config.assets.compile` to `false`. I just checked a few of my apps, and they are all still `false` and run just fine on Heroku.

Comment: Very strange, if I change to false the assets don't show. Even if I run heroku run rake assets:precompile

Comment: I have done some further research and it seems for heroku `config.assets.compile` must be `true` to serve images - In order to have the pre-compile for .js enabled `intitialisers/assets.rb` requires the following `Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( *.js)` - using this method manages to compress the slug size by 40% too, which is brilliant.

Comment: if **config.assets.compile**  is **true**, there is going to be overhead, but if it is **false** nothing will be shown in heroku. **Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( *.js)** is not unnecessary if asset pipeline is being used.  ** my js still does not work in heroku**